# Button size above the table cell

Tags: html, css, web

How to set a button to be the same size as a table cell, but so that it changes its size at different monitor resolutions like this same cell. At the same time being exactly above it (z-index?).

[Table without button display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF9g2.png)

[Button display when pointing to the right half of a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evowd.png)

[Button display when hovering over the left half of a cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nowDP.png)

[The problem with stretching the button for the entire cell size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9NTf.png)

```css
.journal-form {
  margin: 0 0 -25px 0;
}

.journal-btn {
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 30px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.journal-btn-left:hover {
  background-color: #E74C3C;
}

.journal-btn-right:hover {
  background-color: #2ECC71;
}
```

```html
<td>1. Иван Иванов</td>
<td class="p-0 journal-td">
  <div class="journal-grade">3</div>
  <div class="top-layer">
    <form class="form-group journal-form" action="journal-teacher.html" method="get">
      <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
        <div class="btn-group container-fluid p-0" role="group" aria-label="First group">
          <button type="button" class="btn journal-btn journal-btn-left"></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn journal-btn journal-btn-right"></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? We need to see you have tried for yourself, and also some code to work from

Comment: Yes, I tried, but this is a very bad solution

Answer (score 0):

You can set your buttons to `position: absolute` and make them 50% width, like this:

```
.journal-td {
  position: relative;
}
.journal-td button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}
.journal-td button.journal-btn-right {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ejqkfow/